# Copying Files based on a custom column value between document libraries in SharePoint using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, sharepoint, file-copying

I am new to Javascript and currently working on a task where I need to copy files based on a **custom column name "PID"** from One Document Library to the other.

I was able to get the below code to work which copies all the files

```
$scope.copyFiles=function()
{

var sourceLib = '/sites/Protocol/ProtocolDocument';
var destLib = '/sites/Protocol/FinalProtocolDocuments';


var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var web = context.get_web().get_lists();
var folderSrc = web.getFolderByServerRelativeUrl(sourceLib);
//var cq = "<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name="ProtocolID" LookupId="TRUE"/><Value Type="Text">' + 466 + '</Value></Eq></Where></Query>"
context.load(folderSrc,'Files');
context.executeQueryAsync(
function() {

           console.log("Got the source folder right here!");
           var files = folderSrc.get_files();
           var e = files.getEnumerator();
           var dest = [];
           while (e.moveNext()) {
           var file = e.get_current();
           var destLibUrl = destLib + "/" + file.get_name();
           dest.push(destLibUrl); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
           file.copyTo(destLibUrl, true);

           }

        console.log(dest); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
        context.executeQueryAsync(function() { console.log("Files moved successfully!");}, function(sender, args) {console.log("error: ") + args.get_message()});
        }, 
    function(sender, args){console.log("Sorry, something messed up: " + args.get_message());}
    );   

   }
```

I did some research online to get the Filenames based on a custom column value with no luck

Also tried to use CAML , however not sure how to use it in the code.

Would appreciate if anyone could help me get the filenames from a Document Library based on custom column name "PID" so that only selected/filtered files are moved to the destination Library.

***UPDATED CODE***

```
$scope.copyFiles=function()
{
   var sourceLib = '/sites/Protocol/ProtocolDocument';
   var destLib = '/sites/Protocol/FinalProtocolDocuments';
   PID='466'
   var context = new SP.ClientContext();
   var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("ProtocolDocument");
   var cq = new SP.CamlQuery();
   cq.set_viewXml("<View><Query>" +
                  "<Where>" +
                  "<Eq><FieldRef Name=\"ProtocolID\"/><Value Type=\"Text\">PID</Value></Eq>" +
                  "</Where>" +
                  "</Query>" +
                  "</View>");

   var items = list.getItems(cq);
   context.load(items);
   context.executeQueryAsync(
   function() {
                 var e = items.getEnumerator();
                 var dest = [];
                 while (e.moveNext()) 
                 {
                   var file = e.get_current();
                   var destLibUrl = destLib + "/" + file.get_name();
                   dest.push(destLibUrl); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
                   file.copyTo(destLibUrl, true);

                 }

        console.log(dest); //delete this when we're happy we got the file paths right
        context.executeQueryAsync(function() { console.log("Files moved successfully!");}, function(sender, args) {console.log("error: ") + args.get_message()});
        }, 
    function(sender, args){console.log("Sorry, something messed up: " + args.get_message());}
    );   

 }          

});
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you would like to copy documents with PID set to something, from one document library to another? If so, what column type is the PID column, and do you have any examples on documents that should be moved?

Comment: @runar thank you for the response... PID is a lookup column that has a value and is the project ID and every PID has 5 documents associated with it on successful project completion...As the code is in testing phase , any 5 PDF or words documents could be taken as an example. Please let me know if any other information is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my attempt. I tested it successfully on SharePoint 2013, and it copies files from one document library to another, but only the files with a lookup field set to a specific value. I have included a short summary, but if you only want the code then jump down to **Now to the actual code**.

Please note that I have used syntax not supported by Internet Explorer, so let me know if you need to support that browser. I also believe that a function or method should only do one thing, so I split the functionality into three separate functions. This also helps keep the code clean and easier to read.

To summarize: The first function, `findAndCopyFiles()`, will run once and find all the files with the lookup field value you set. It will then send each file to the `loadAndCopyFile()` function to load the file object. This function will run once for every file that should be copied. When the file object is loaded, it is sent to the third and final function, `copyFileTo()`, that will actually copy the file to the destination document library. This function will also run once per file.

**Now to the actual code**

First you need to set these configuration variables according to your setup:

```js
const destinationLibraryPath = 'The path to your destination document library';
const sourceLibraryName = 'The name (not path) of your source document library';
const lookupField = 'The name of your lookup field';
const lookupValue = 'The value your lookup field should equal for files to be copied';
```

**findAndCopyFiles()**

This function is responsible for finding all the files in the source document library with the lookup field set to the value of `lookupValue`. We use what is known as a [CAML query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245851(v%3Doffice.15)) to filter the files. You can filter on all available fields and columns, not only lookup fields.

```js
const findAndCopyFiles = () => {
    const clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    const sourceList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(sourceLibraryName);

    const camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    const whereQuery = `<Eq><FieldRef Name="${lookupField}"/><Value Type="Text">${lookupValue}</Value></Eq>`;
    camlQuery.set_viewXml(`<View><Query><Where>${whereQuery}</Where></Query></View>`);

    const sourceListItems = sourceList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(sourceListItems);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        () => {
            const filesEnumerator = sourceListItems.getEnumerator();
            while (filesEnumerator.moveNext()) {
                loadAndCopyFile(filesEnumerator.get_current(), clientContext);
            }
        },
        (_sender, args) => {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
```

When the query executes, we use the [`getEnumerator()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ee659727(v=office.14)) method to iterate through all the files returned by the query, in other words all the files that will be copied.

**loadAndCopyFile()**

After finding all the relevant files, we send each file to the next function to continue our process. This function will load the file object (as in the actual file) and construct the destination URL using the path to the destination document library and the filename of the file.

```js
const loadAndCopyFile = (file, clientContext) => {
    const fileRef = file.get_file();

    clientContext.load(fileRef);
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        () => {
            const destinationUrl = `${destinationLibraryPath}/${fileRef.get_name()}`;
            copyFileTo(fileRef, destinationUrl, clientContext);
        },
        (_sender, args) => {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
```

**copyFileTo()**

The final function is responsible for actually copying the file to the destination document library. It is quite simple, and looks like this:

```js
const copyFileTo = (file, destinationUrl, clientContext) => {
    file.copyTo(destinationUrl, true);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        () => {
            console.log(`File copied to ${destinationUrl}!`);
        },
        (_sender, args) => {
            console.log(args.get_message());
        }
    );
}
```

**Putting it all together**

And finally, we execute the `findAndCopyFiles()` function when all the required libraries are ready:

```js
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', () => {
    findAndCopyFiles();
});
```

Disclaimer: I wrote this post on another computer than the one where I tested the code, so if something does not work it may be because of a simple syntax error. In that case, add a comment and let me know!

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed explanation , I am going through the above code and trying to implement it , Since there are around 3 functions , Do I have to include the last 2 functions inside  findAndCopyFiles() ?

Also I made some changes to my code.I do not get any errors as such , However no files are copied for some reason , Can you please help me out with that? Can you also suggest where I should be posting my updated code?
Thank you once again :)

Comment: The code should be organized [like this](https://pastebin.com/0tUhutNZ). Just one file (or inside `<script></script>` tags), not inside each other. Take a look at the link and you will understand. Regarding your updated code: You can edit your original question and add the new code at the bottom.

Comment: Thank You once again for the prompt response. I have added the new code to the Updated Code section , would request you to check and let me know

Comment: Would you please try this: Replace your `$scope.copyFiles()` function with [this](https://pastebin.com/bBdJiNGd), and if it still does not work, then look in your developer console for any error messages.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the code sequence , I would surely give this a try 

Thank you very much :)

Comment: No problem! Please let me know how it goes, and do not hesitate to ask again if it still does not work.

Comment: Thank you very much for all the help , the code works as expected and I am able to copy the required files to the destination.

Being a learner , I tried to write the code on my own after a lot of research online and believe there are minute errors in it.

Would you please take a look and let me know what might have gone wrong and suggest changes so that I learn from them? 

I have included the code under the "Updated Code" section.

Thank you once again.